# Get Total Photo Count via Facebook Graph API

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to get the **total photo count** of a user.

I tried these

`me?fields=photos.limit(200).fields(images)`
this returns id,not photo count

`me/albums?fields=photos`

`me/albums?fields=photos?fields=source,name,id`

`me/albums?fields=photos&fields=source,name,id`
gives cover photo ,profile photo

`me?fields=albums.fields(id,name,cover_photo,photos.fields`

on [Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with required permissions but either they are giving unnecessary info or the API returns an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `count` field for each album

`me/albums?fields=count,name`

Comment: Its giving this response...{
  "data": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "name": "Cover Photos",
      "id": "1766543212334015"
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "name": "Profile Pictures",
      "id": "138888888888336"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MTMytrewqsdfghc4MDE1",
      "after": "MTjjhhhhhhhhMjc4MzM2"
    }
  }
}...there is no total-photo-count here

Comment: According to that response, it does. 1 photo in Cover Photos and 1 photo Profile PIctures. This is how you get the count, if it's not working, you are either not telling me something (like you are using a Test User, or trying to get a photo count not belonging to you) or you need to file a bug @Sadaquat

Comment: ...actually i am using my facebook id for this and testing quries on graph API explorer, also i have provided all the required permission.I want to get total-photo-count i.e the photo that are present in my photo folder.In my photo menu there are 4 photos.so it should return 4

Comment: What's your profile id then, because the photos above resolve to nothing @Sadaquat

Comment: oh..thanks it worked now, it shows all three,the total timeline photos,cover and profile.I have to wait for tomorrow to check it on my development machine,to make sure.Again thanks...

Comment: yes it works but i am getting other fields using this...fb.GetAsync("me?fields=name,friends") so in this case albums?fields=count,name would not work,so what string should be generated in this case?

Comment: `me?fields=name,friends,albums{count}`

Comment: Excellent..it works..for optimization this is returned as "albums": {
    "data": [
      {
        "count": 2,
        "id": "136187116725713"
      },
      {
        "count": 4,
        "id": "136185663392525"
      },
      {
        "count": 2,
        "id": "135853410092417"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "id": "133997430278015"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "id": "133994220278336"
      }   ...means i have to access all these counts and then i will add them one by one to get the total, Is there any alternate to get total-count atonce